# How to use pointers to figure out if a c-string ends with another c-string?

Tags: c++, c-strings

So for my assignment, I have to complete the function endsWith which returns true if s1 ends with s2 (both cstrings)

Example: "sailboat", "boat" -> true
Example: "mississipii", "pie" -> false

I already successfully did the program startsWith, which returns true if s1 starts with s2

```
bool startsWith(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
   // enter code under here
   while (*s1)
   {
      auto *p1 = s1, *p2 = s2;
      while (*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2)
      {
         p1++;
         p2++;
      }
      if (*p2 == '\0') {return true;}
      else {return false;}
   }
   // enter code above this line
}
```

and this is the program my professor said use to find the last occurrence of a character:

```
int find(const char a[], char target)
{
   int result = -1;
   for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; ++i)
      if (a[i] == target)
         result = i;
   return result;
}
```

but I'm struggling finding a way of connecting the two to make endsWith. All of my attempts end with errors. And I will be the vary first to admit I have little idea what pointers really are or how to use them or what their purpose is at all, and it is by pure luck the first one passed.

This is my latest failed attempt without pointers, and it passed 5 out of 9 tests:

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
bool endsWith(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
   int len1 = strlen(s1);
   int len2 = strlen(s2);
   // enter code under here

 if (len2 > len1) {return false;}
   for (size_t i = 0; i < len1; ++i)
   {
      if(s1[len1 - i - 1] != s2[len2 - i - 1]) {return false;}
   }
   return true;

   // enter code above here
}
```

Edit: This is the code that works:

```
if (len2 > len1) {return false;}
   size_t offset = len1 - len2;
   s1 += offset;
   return (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0);
```

Comment: Ah! Apologies for confusion. We're writing learning how to write C code using C++. Or is it C code in a C++ program? It's a C++ class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged your question as C++, but your code technically suggests "C", which is fine with me.

A "C" solution

```
// returns true if "s2" ends with "s1"
// examples s1="World" and s2="Hello World" => returns true
// examples s1="Hello" and s2="Hello World" => returns false
bool endsWith(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);

    // if s1 is longer than s2, then we can trivially reject it
    if (len1 > len2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    size_t offset = len2 - len1;
    s2 += offset;
    return (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0);
   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to edit it a tiny bit, but this ultimately worked!

Comment: @Michele - don't forget to upvote/accept if you found the answer useful. What was the "tiny bit" you had to edit?

Comment: I just had to switch around the len1 and len2 values, it wasn't anything big! I put the working code at the end of my question if you want to look at it. Thank you, again ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it in [my C++ project](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly/blob/202899f22c9293208f5b7f06a5869de546e3778c/AECforWebAssembly.cpp#L25):

```cpp
bool ends_with(string first, string second) {
  if (second.size() > first.size())
    return false;
  return first.substr(first.size() - second.size()) == second;
}
```

Comment: @selbie What does `const char string&` mean? Specifically, what does `char` mean there?

Comment: Oops.. Typo!  I meant to say **const string&**.  Brain fart.  I'm going to delete and repeat.

Comment: **corrected comment**: You should pass those strings into your function as `const string&` instead of `string` - avoids the copy and enables optimizations.  Also, enables callers to pass string literals and `char*` instances as well without much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to write it yourself for practice.

But if you need to do it in real-world code, here's a one-liner: (requires C++20)

```
std::string_view(s1).ends_with(s2)
```